# Accessing SQL Server table dependent upon another table

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am am experience mainframe programmer, but new to SQL Server & learning vb.net so I realise that this is probably very basic, apologies in advance ...

I have a `DataTable` called `MailTypes` which contains 2 columns, the `ID` & the `Name`.

I have a `DataTable` called `Leagues` which contains a lot of columns, one of which is a foreign key linked to the `MailTypes` primary key, which I want to access once for every row in the `MailTypes` table & use the `MailType` `Name` each time through.

What is the best way to do this ?

As an example ...

```
MailTypeID ... MailTypeName

     1     ...    Pass 1
     2     ...    Pass 2
     3     ...    Pass 3

LeagueID ... LeagueName ... MailTypeID

     1   ...   League1  ...    2
     2   ...   League2  ...    3
     3   ...   League3  ...    2
     4   ...   League4  ...    1
     5   ...   League5  ...    1
     6   ...   League6  ...    3
```

I want my Output (after formatting) to be

```
Pass 1

League4

League5

Pass2

League1

League3

Pass3

League2

League6
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are searching for the sql command required this could be your answer

```
SELECT m.MailTypeName, l.LeagueName
FROM MailTypes m INNER JOIN Leagues l ON m.MaiTypeID=l.MailTypeID
ORDER BY m.MailTypeName
```

if you are searching for how to display this data, then it depends on the technology used (WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET, MVC etc....

Comment: It is the SQL, yes, Andrew, I fully understand the logic just no idea how to do it <blush> !!! Thank you, I will mess around wit hthis in the morning and see if I can get it to work ... thank uou ...

Comment: Sorry, I've been avoiding this program for the past couple of days, I was so frustrated ... I'll try this tomorrow & see how I get on, thank you ...